# Building Celery container in Django app

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, yaml, celery

I want to learn how to set up a Django app with Celery. I am using the following [resource](https://blog.syncano.io/configuring-running-django-celery-docker-containers-pt-1/).

I don't understand why we have to build the same image twice for both `web` and `worker` this example. For example, see:

```
# Django web server
web:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  hostname: web
  command: ./run_web.sh
  volumes:
    - .:/app  # mount current directory inside container
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  # set up links so that web knows about db, rabbit and redis
  links:
    - db
    - rabbit
    - redis
  depends_on:
    - db

# Celery worker
worker:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  command: ./run_celery.sh
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - db
    - rabbit
    - redis
  depends_on:
    - rabbit
```

Does that mean that this docker-compose.yml will create two containers that are duplicates of each other? Seems a little excessive if I just need a celery worker for `worker` (why set up Django twice?). Maybe I am misunderstanding things. It feels like one option is to just replace `command` in `web` with `./run_web.sh; ./run_celery.sh` and just set up proper links. This way you could remove `worker` altogether. 
Can someone enlighten me? Thanks for reading.